# SQL Server Windows Authentication with different credentials

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string, windows-authentication

I have two different userid and passwords for windows:admin and normal-user

I have logged into SSMS as admin and created a database, now I want my .NET application to connect to it:

Trial 1:

`packet size=4096;Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=True;initial catalog=arrbtr_vlimits3`

of course did not work

> login failed for user [normal-user-id]

Trial 2:

`packet size=4096;persist security info=False;Server=[server-name];user id=[admin-id];password=[admin-pwd];initial catalog=arrbtr_vlimits3`

> login failed for user [admin-user-id]

Note: logging into SSMS as normal user is a problem for some reason

Comment: The `User ID` and `Password` connection parameters are used for SQL Logins, whereas `Trusted_Connection=True` is used for Windows/Active Directory logins. The latter uses the authentication token attached to the current process. If you need it to login using a different Windows account then run the process using something like [`runas`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)), or code the process to use [impersonation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows Authentication, you need to set up a login for `normal-user-id`. Usernames and passwords in the connection string do not work because they are only used for SQL Authentication.

I would advise you ideally to use an AD group, but if not then you can create a login just for that Windows user.

```sql
USE master;

CREATE LOGIN [YourDomain\normal-user-id] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = arrbtr_vlimits3;
```

You then need to create a user for that login within the database

```sql
USE arrbtr_vlimits3;

CREATE USER [YourDomain\normal-user-id] FROM LOGIN [YourDomain\normal-user-id];
```

Then give them permissions

```sql
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [YourDomain\normal-user-id];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [YourDomain\normal-user-id];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Comment: Give that Database Access to Normal-User-ID as well. By going into Permissions option of that Database.